# Is it possible to find which server an android application connects to

Tags: android, download, backtrace

I am wondering if it is possible to trace which server an application connects to to get data. I'm thinking of using the Google APK Expansion to bundle my media files (textures, video's etc) and was wondering since the LVL is said to be so buggy, if it wouldn't be better to store those files on a zip on a separate server and download them during first run time and unzip them into internal storage, then delete those files.

So is it possible to trace which server the file or info comes from and if so is there any way to make it a bit more difficult to do so.

Thanks any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There are many ways to do this depending on the scenario.  [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) promiscuous mode on a Wi-Fi network is just one.

There is no point in trying to obfuscate this.

Comment: So it would be best if my files were encrypted on the server and decryped when downloaded right?

Comment: Maybe.  It may not make any difference if you just have a single hard-coded key in your APK.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of using some combination of on server encryption with a decryption key being sent after verification was received that apk signature was not changed, or something like that.